# Date comparison logic

Tags: apex

This is probably something super simple but I can't see it right now. I have the following block of code that keeps entering an if statement when I don't want it to.

```
trigger acctOppTrigger on Opportunity (before update) {

Set<Id> AccountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Opportunity op : Trigger.new) {
        accountIds.add(op.AccountId);
    }

Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT First_Order_Date__c FROM Account 
                                               WHERE Id IN :accountIds]);

DateTime firstOrder;

for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {

// add the account name
firstOrder = accountMap.get(o.AccountId).First_Order_Date__c;

        //create an instance of the opportunity helper class
        OpportunityHelper myHelper = new OpportunityHelper();
        myHelper.closingTime(o.CreatedDate);

        //TEMP: Toggle field for testing - trigger only fires when true
        If (o.Ready_to_Close__c ){

//this portion works properly when I manipulate a record in the UI
if (firstOrder != null && myHelper.firstOrderInsideWindow(firstOrder, o.CreatedDate)){
                o.StageName = 'Closed Won'; 
                o.CloseDate = Date.today();
            }

            //this is where the problem is, even if I change the < to > it still updates the record to 'Closed Lost' in the UI and my tests fail
            else {

                if (CreatedDate.addDays(60) < Date.today()){               
                   o.Loss_Reason__c = 'closed automagically';
                   o.StageName = 'Closed Lost';
                   o.CloseDate = Date.today();   
                }
            }
```

}

For more context - the helper method is as follows:

```
public Boolean firstOrderInsideWindow (DateTime FirstOrderDate, DateTime CreatedDate){
    if (CreatedDate.addDays(60) > FirstOrderDate){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be `o.CreatedDate`?  Also, this would be expected behavior if `CreatedDate` is exactly 60 days before today.

Comment: This post does not contain enough context to be answerable. What does `myHelper.firstOrderInsideWindow` do?  What data type is `firstOrder`?

Comment: 1. I have added the helper method code (that seems to be working fine). 2. `firstOrder` is a DateTime data type.

Comment: if `o.CreatedDate` is exactly 60 days before today I would expect it to not close (although you have a good point I have not included the <= code for that).

Comment: How exactly are you getting `firstOrder`? Without knowing where it comes from, answering this question is still just a guessing game.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the rest of the trigger code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That helper method is barely necessary, since it just performs a Boolean comparison. If we inline it, the logic looks like this:

```
if (firstOrder != null && o.CreatedDate.addDays(60) > firstOrder )){
    o.StageName = 'Closed Won'; 
    o.CloseDate = Date.today();
} else {
    if (CreatedDate.addDays(60) < Date.today()) {               
        o.Loss_Reason__c = 'closed automagically';
        o.StageName = 'Closed Lost';
        o.CloseDate = Date.today();   
    }
}
```

There are three possible outcomes from this logic:

1. The outer `if` condition evaluates to true (created date + 60 days is greater than `firstOrder`), in which case the Opportunity is marked Closed Won.
2. The outer `if` condition is false, but the nested `if` condition is true. In this case, we mark the Opportunity Closed Lost. **Note** that you're referring to some local variable `CreatedDate` here rather than `o.CreatedDate`, which may not compile and may not do what you want. This may be a source of an issue, or it may be a typo in your code paste.
3. The `if` condition is false, but the condition in the nested `if` is *also* false. In this case, nothing happens. This would probably be the case if the created date is exactly 60 days ago, depending on what `firstOrder` is. But note as in (2) that you seem to be referring to the wrong value for `CreatedDate` in this condition.

The fact that you are making comparisons between different dates in the nested `if` clauses can make it tricky to mentally evaluate which code path is followed by any given record. Adding `System.debug()` statements in each arm of your logic can help to establish which record ends up where.

Comment: Also it maybe be better to just do `Date.today().daysBetween(CreatedDate)` (which would then check against a negative value I think).

Comment: Problem solved. It was an old workflow that was setting it back on me. But, I did take all of this advice and refactored my code and it's much more readable now. Thank you everyone for your input.